# Eclipse plugin for compile after change in java class and deploy automatically after build

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm using Eclipse and Tomcat server for my project.

Whenever I do some changes in my project, if I made any changes in java classes, I need to build.

I want to know if there is any possibility of causing my changes without building the war again?

And is there any plugin available for eclipse to automatically deploy the war after building it?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Maven, [Cargo plugin](http://cargo.codehaus.org/Deploying+to+a+running+container) is the best option for you that supports deploying to an already running container.